# Can't login ("Access Denied") with PBIS without network connection

Tags: login, active-directory

I'm using PBIS (from pbis-open* packages) to log on my PC using Active Directory account. (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04)

It works fine as long as I have a network connection on the domain.
But when I'm disconnected from the network, when trying to login, I got an "Access denied" error. (It's not a wrong password issue...)

My understanding is that I should be able to connect even without network because PBIS provide cached credential feature.

In /var/log/auth.log, I'm getting this error:

> [lsass-pam] [module:pam_lsass]User *my_username* is denied access
>   because they are not in the 'require membership of' list

This looks clearly to be the root of my issue, but I can't figure out how to fix this...

Any hint ?

Thanks!

Comment: There probably is a group for PBIS that you have to be a member of to get access to auth.log

Answer (score 1):

If you type the PBIS you will get a list of commands. There is one in the documentation that is like this

```
/opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf #groupname
```

if you put in your group name here this should fix it... keep in mind if this is a directory group it will be `DOMAIN\\GroupName`